# Is it possible to disable jquery datatable exports for devices?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to disable the export functionality of the jquery datatable, I am looking for some in build solution provided by jquery data table.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this link you have needed,

[DataTable Enable / disable](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/api/enable.html)